# Can't implement the pie chart like a ring in CorePlot

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts, core-plot, pie-chart

I use iOS CorePlot to implement a Pie Chart in my app.

The design is:

[image]

but my result is not so perfect:

[image]

Is there a way to make this chart like a ring and add the white space between the sections?

Comment: Do u have to use Core Plot necessarily ? Because it can be done with QuartzCore framework.

Answer (score 1):

```
pieChart.pieInnerRadius
```

solved the issue - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set the `pieInnerRadius` to make a ring. Use the `borderLineStyle` to make the white lines between the pie slices.